# XSLT tables out of order in output

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have tables like this:
< table hidden="" class="table">
    < colgroup data-cols="6">
        < col style="width:.75in;text-align:left" data-colname="col1">
        < col style="width:0.8in;text-align:center" data-colname="col2">
        < col style="width:0.76in;" data-colname="col3">
        < col style="width:2.47in;" data-colname="col4">
        < col style="text-align:left" data-colname="col5">
        < col style="width:0.8in;text-align:center" data-colname="col6">
        < thead>
            < tr class="headerRow">
                < th>Text< /th>
                < th>Texttext< /th>
                < th>Text< /th>
                < th>Text< /th>
                < th>Text< /th>
                < th>Text Text< /th>
            < /tr>
        < /thead>
        < tbody>
            < tr>
                < td>< span hidden="" class="num">< /td>
                < td>Text< /td>
                < td>Text< /td>
                < td>Text< /td>
                < td>Text< /td>
            < /tr>
        < /tbody>
    < /colgroup>
< / table>

I have XSLT Template matches like this (deleted attribute matches because they're not needed for this example):

```
<xsl:template match="colgroup">
    <tgroup>                    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::col | descendant::thead | descendant::tbody"/>
    </tgroup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="col">
    <colspec>         
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </colspec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thead">
    <thead>                       
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </thead>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody">
    <tbody>                      
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>
```

The result I am getting is:
< table hidden="" class="table">
    < tgroup data-cols="6">
        < colspec style="width:.75in;text-align:left" data-colname="col1">
        < colspec style="width:0.8in;text-align:center" data-colname="col2">
        < colspec style="width:0.76in;" data-colname="col3">
        < colspec style="width:2.47in;" data-colname="col4">
        < colspec style="text-align:left" data-colname="col5">
        < colspec style="width:0.8in;text-align:center" data-colname="col6">
      < /tgroup>
      < thead>
            < row class="headerRow">
                < entry>Text< /entry>
                < entry>Texttext< /entry>
                < entry>Text< /entry>
                < entry>Text< /entry>
                < entry>Text< /entry>
                < entry>Text Text< /entry>
            < /row>
        < /thead>
        < tbody>
            < row>
                < entry>< span hidden="" class="num">< /entry>
                < entry>Text< /entry>
                < entry>Text< /entry>
                < entry>Text< /entry>
                < entry>Text< /entry>
            < /row>
        < /tbody>
< / table>

The THEAD and TBODY should be inside the colgroup at the same level as the COL elements, but I can't seem to get it to cooperate.

Comment: In addition to Alochi's answer, it looks like none of your templates are getting matched anyway, If the "colgroup" one is matched, the output should contain a "tgroup" element, which is not the case if your output is accurate. Does your actual html input contain a namespace declaration of the form `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`?

Comment: How are you doing the transformation and how are you viewing the output? If you are sending the output to an HTML engine of any kind, then it will try to reorganize the table to make it HTML-valid.

Answer (score 0):

You're producing HTML output. In HTML, colgroups only contain col elements, not thead or tbody elements. Your outputter is fixing your HTML for you.

If you don't want that to happen, don't ask your outputter to generate HTML.

Comment: This conversion is actually taking an HTML file to XML. In the HTML file, the table appears as required with the thead and tbody within the colgroup tag.  The output method is set to XML.

Comment: Something is writing it to HTML. See how there are no `</th>`  and `</td>` tags either. That's not XML.

Comment: But it might be the HTML to XML step at the start that is taking the thead and tbody out of the colgroup. Either way, the invalidity of the HTML is your problem.

Comment: ...My apologies, I copied and pasted the output incorrectly and forgot to put the space in the end tags so they were escaped. I edited my post. I am going to try to fix the HTML (I run a conversion script to go from XML to HTML that puts it in that order) to see if valid HTML would prevent it from breaking.

Comment: Alohci, Thanks for the response. When I changed the HTML file to output the elements in valid order, I am able to now match them in the XML order I need them to be in. I don't know why it didn't dawn on me earlier! Now, I gotta figure out how to get only the "apply-templates" call for the thead and tbody to work and not the template for them? (I think)